# Remove Event Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on 8th wall to design an interactive augmented reality experience. I'm combining code from this page https://www.8thwall.com/8thwall/placeground-aframe/master/tap-place.js where I can place a 3d object when I tap the screen. Now I would like to make them disappear after an x time. Thanks in advance.

```
export const tapPlaceComponent = {
  init() {
    const ground = document.getElementById('ground')
    ground.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      // Create new entity for the new object
      const newElement = document.createElement('a-entity')
      // The raycaster gives a location of the touch in the scene
      const touchPoint = event.detail.intersection.point
      newElement.setAttribute('position', touchPoint)
     // const randomYRotation = Math.random() * 360
      newElement.setAttribute('rotation', `0 0 0`)
      newElement.setAttribute('visible', 'false')
      newElement.setAttribute('scale', 'false')
      newElement.setAttribute('shadow', {
        receive: false,
      })

      newElement.setAttribute('gltf-model', '#heartModel')
      this.el.sceneEl.appendChild(newElement)
      newElement.addEventListener('model-loaded', () => {
        // Once the model is loaded, we are ready to show it popping in using an animation
        newElement.setAttribute('visible', 'true')
        newElement.setAttribute('animation', {
          property: 'scale',
          to: '7 7 7',
          easing: 'easeOutElastic',
          dur: 800,
        })
      })
    })
  },
}
setTimeout(tapPlaceComponent, 500)
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` to remove the element after a time period.

Comment: Thank so much @Barmar, but I tried it and it doesn't work. I'm sure its wrong, just don't know where to place the setTimeout(). ' ' –

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout` should be inside the function that creates the new element, and it should remove the element.

The first argument to `setTimeout` must be a function, `tapLaceComponent` is an object.

```js
export const tapPlaceComponent = {
  init() {
    const ground = document.getElementById('ground')
    ground.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      // Create new entity for the new object
      const newElement = document.createElement('a-entity')
      // The raycaster gives a location of the touch in the scene
      const touchPoint = event.detail.intersection.point
      newElement.setAttribute('position', touchPoint)
      // const randomYRotation = Math.random() * 360
      newElement.setAttribute('rotation', `0 0 0`)
      newElement.setAttribute('visible', 'false')
      newElement.setAttribute('scale', 'false')
      newElement.setAttribute('shadow', {
        receive: false,
      })

      newElement.setAttribute('gltf-model', '#heartModel')
      this.el.sceneEl.appendChild(newElement)
      newElement.addEventListener('model-loaded', () => {
        // Once the model is loaded, we are ready to show it popping in using an animation
        newElement.setAttribute('visible', 'true')
        newElement.setAttribute('animation', {
          property: 'scale',
          to: '7 7 7',
          easing: 'easeOutElastic',
          dur: 800,
        });
        // Remove after 2 seconds
        setTimeout(() => newElement.remove(), 2000);
      })
    })
  },
}
```

Comment: thank you so much Barmar!  =) you are amazing!